# Why does a generic and a non-generic IComparable interface exist?

Tags: c#, icomparable

Perhaps this question sounds silly, but why does a [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) and a [non-generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IComparable.aspx) `IComparable` interface exist?

Furthermore, which one is prefered to use and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-generic `IComparable` was added in version 1.1 before generics were introduced, while `IComparer<T>` was added alongside generics in version 2.0.

The generic version is preferred for the same reason as all generic interfaces - it is safer and documents the intent more clearly. Struct types also do not need to be boxed when passed to a generic method, as they would be for one with an `object` argument like `IComparable.CompareTo` so there is also a performance benefit.

Comment: Thank you. The non-generic version was not removed due to compatibility reasons, I guess?

Comment: _And_ if it's used against a `struct` it will pass it without boxing it.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood Right: there was no reason to actively *break* the developers who used the non-generic interface. They were free to upgrade at their leisure, of course.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - I've updated the answer to include the boxing advantage.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood Removing all non-generic versions of classes would have meant that all pre-2.0 .NET code would have ceased to function. That's not something you want. As a side note: Java had the same issue and went a different path: Instead of having non-generic and generic classes, they turned generics into a compiler feature instead of a language feature: After compilation, all generic type information is gone, using normal non-generic classes. This is known as type erasure. I would call this the worst decision ever made by the Java guys, by the way.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Oh I see, thank you for the background information. This is very interesting to me. I heard of the Java's type erasure in the context of Scala, where it is also a problem. Knowing the background, I see the reason to keep the non-generic versions. But at first glance, I was very confused, I must admit.